# Match function? VBA not working properly

Tags: excel, function, vba, match

I have a following code and i have "name" in cells B11 , B19 and B25 and i was expecting a result of 19 or 25 with the code but it returns Y=1. Could anyone tell me what is the problem?.

```
Sub mat()

Y = Application.Match("name", ActiveSheet.Range("B19:B30"), 0)
MsgBox Y

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation for MATCH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835873.aspx):

> MATCH returns the position of the matched value within lookup_array, not the value itself.

and with `0`as the optional third argument (`match_type`):

> If match_type is 0, MATCH finds the first value that is exactly equal to lookup_value. Lookup_array can be in any order.

So the returned `1`refers to the position on `B19`in the array `Range("B19:B30")` and the code sample is indeed behaving as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
Application.Match("name", ActiveSheet.Range("B19:B30"), 0)
```

The MATCH function searches for a specified item in a range of cells, and then returns the **relative position** of that item in the range

So parsing the parameter `ActiveSheet.Range("B19:B30")` means that `B19` equals **relative position** `=1`.

Answer (score 0):

add slgn

```
Sub mat()
    Y = Application.Match(slng(range("a4").value), ActiveSheet.Range("B19:B30"), 0)
    MsgBox Y
End Sub
```

ex2:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CLng(TextBox1.Text), sheet110.Range("B6:B" & ls), 0)
```