# How to apply MATCH() function in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am trying to run the code below but get

> Error 1004: Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class.

I understand if there is no match, MATCH() function returns *#N/A*, so there is no point to assign this to the INDEX variable (moreover, I think it might also cause an error).

How can I account for this possibility?

```
Sub Debugging()

Workbooks("Problem.xls").Worksheets(1).Activate

Cash_Rows = 5
Share_Rows = 6

If Cash_Rows <= Share_Rows Then

    Range("A1:A" & Cash_Rows).Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
        .TintAndShade = 0.399975585192419 
    End With

    Count_Cash = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), "L*")

    For Each cell In Range("A1:A" & Cash_Rows)
        If CStr(cell.Value) Like "L*" Then
            Range("A" & cell.Row & ":" & "D" & cell.Row).Interior.Color = 65535
            Dim Index As Integer
            Index = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CStr(cell.Value), Range("F2:" & "F" & Share_Rows), 0)
            Range("F" & Index & ":" & "I" & Index).Interior.Color = 65535
        End If
    Next

    If Count_Cash = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You do not have any matching ID+Amount between Cash and Shares booking. It's OK!"
    Else
        MsgBox "You have " & Count_Cash & " matching transactions. Check them!"
    End If 

Else 

    MsgBox "Do not worry. Be happy!" 

End If 

End Sub
```

Comment: What version of Excel?  You could try `Application.Match` instead of `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20028769/match-function-vba-not-working-properly?rq=1).  **PS** Welcome to the site!  Please check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more info about asking questions that will attract quality answers.

Comment: Thank you for reply! I am using Excel 2010. Your tip actually helped, but only when I changed declaration of "Index" variable - from Integer type to the Variant (otherwise I got _Type Mismatch_ error). I think it relates to the potential issue I mentioned in my question - if MATCH() function at some point returns "#N/A" instead of a number you get an error - because you explicitly said that Index can only be Integer. The problem that remains is that this code will not run further unless I handle the possibility of getting "#N/A" from MATCH(). So, I will think now what to do about it.

Comment: I think you can just use cell instead of CStr(cell.value), strange this is a function I use and it works well for me. I usually get it working in excel first in a formula, then change that formula into vba code afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use `Application.Match` instead of `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match`.  The error indicates that `Match` itself is missing, not that the arguments to `Match` are problematic.  (Not sure why `Match` should be missing, though!)
2. As you mentioned in your comment, `Dim Index as Variant` rather than as `Integer`.  (Incidentally, [use `Long` instead of `Integer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/2877364) unless you're calling a 16-bit-only API function.)
3. Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27302888/2877364), `Application.Match` returns an error Variant if the match fails (`#N/A`).  To test for that, use `IsError`:

   ```
   If Not IsError(Index) Then
       Dim idxstr as String: idxstr = CStr(Index)
           ' ^^ Make sure you don't get surprised by how the Variant converts
       Range("F" & idxstr & ":" & "I" & idxstr).Interior.Color = 65535
   End If
   ```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835873.aspx  expression .Match(Arg1, Arg2, Arg3)
expression A variable that represents a WorksheetFunction object.  it has to be `application.worksheetfunction.match()`

Comment: @Gareth I saw that, too, but [OP says](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38398310/match-function-in-vba/38399444?noredirect=1#comment64206499_38398310) `Application.Match` worked.  See also the linked answer.  I don't have 2010 available, so wasn't able to test there.  On my 2013 install, `Application.Match` does exist, even though it doesn't show up in the Object Browser!

Comment: Thank you all very much! This is exactly what I looked for.